# Cant get PHP value in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

my Php code;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login_speak";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
               $tempArray[] = $row;
    }            
$resultArray = json_encode($tempArray);
echo $resultArray; 

}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

my jquery code;

```
 $.getJSON("url.php", function(data){
           $("ul").empty();
           $.each(data.result, function(){
              $("ul").append("<li>Name:"+this['Name']+"</li>");
              alert("kj");
           });    
    });
```

I have done several things ,But nothing works.I php is correct and I have problem in script ,I guess.
Please give me the answer ,What wrong is done.
Thanks

Comment: i getting error from PHP file ,I think.Please check the Php file

Comment: [{"Name":"please","Password":"dawwww","Role":"Student","Image":"","Active":"","Id":"58"},{"Name":"adai","Password":"vadapanni","Role":"Teacher","Image":"","Active":"","Id":"57"},{"Name":"adai","Password":"vadapanni","Role":"Native","Image":"","Active":"","Id":"56"},{"Name":"adai","Password":"vada","Role":"jhghg","Image":"","Active":"","Id":"55"},{"Name":"manikamj","Password":"hih","Role":"jhghg","Image":"","Active":"","Id":"54"}]

Comment: this my array,is there any problem

Answer (score 2):

json_encode from php can be accessed easily in a Javascript varible
There are many ways of doing this, however consider the simple way first if it works with the array you are sending.
in your example - assuming jquery:

```
  var valu =  [];
    $.ajax(url: "url.php",
           success: function(data){
                  valu=data;
           });
```

see: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php

works for numeric and associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want change your code to something like this..

```
$.each(data.result, function(index,value){
              $("ul").append("<li>Name:"+value.name+"</li>");
              alert("kj");
           });
```

Comment: Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2:40278

Comment: this is in my console

Comment: But data is not in this function it self

 $.getJSON("url.php", function(data){

Comment: try to Use `$.ajax` instead for `$.getJSON`

Comment: Yes, I have used but same result

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I would do.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "url.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
    $.each(codes, function(key,value){
             $("ul").append('<option value="' + key + '">' + key + ' - ' + value + '</option>');
    });
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    alert("error message");
    console.log("error message: " + error);
});
```

Comment: showing error message and in console only "error message" is displayed

Comment: In Firefox, go to developer tools, click network tab and look at response from your php. Make sure there is a response there. I there is an error in the php it will show there.